# Random number corresponding to array of UIColors- ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicolor

I have a function that creates a `CGRect` and I am trying to assign a random color to each of them.

I create the colors as variables with the type `UIColor` and then put them into an array called `colors`. Then, I create a random number generator and call it when defining the background color of the `CGRect`, but I get the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type "[UIColor}"

Why is this? Here is my code:

```
func addBox(location: CGRect) -> UIView {
    let newBox = UIView(frame: location)

    let red = UIColor(red: (242.0/255.0), green: (186.0/255.0), blue: (201.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    let green = UIColor(red: (186.0/255.0), green: (242.0/255.0), blue: (216.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    let yellow = UIColor(red: (242.0/255.0), green: (226.0/255.0), blue: (186.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    let blue = UIColor(red: (186.0/255.0), green: (216.0/255.0), blue: (242.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    let colors = [red, green, yellow, blue]
    let randomNum:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)

    newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(colors(randomNum))

    hView.insertSubview(newBox, at: 0)
    return newBox
}
```

If anyone could solve this that would be amazing. Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: `colors[Int(randomNum)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(colors(randomNum))
```

should be:

```
newBox.backgroundColor = colors[randomNum]
```

`colors` is an array of `UIColor`. You just need one element from the array.

You should also change:

```
let randomNum:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
```

to:

```
let randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(colors.count))
```

This way if you add more colors to the array, you don't need to adjust this line. It makes your code less error prone.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much!! It looks like that would work but I'm getting an error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIColor]' with an index of type 'UInt32'. Do you know why that is?

Comment: See my update. You need to case the result of `arc4random_uniform` to `Int`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.

Comment: And of course I meant "cast", not "case" in my previous comment.